# line of code is not displaying the title format after running it

Tags: python, title

I've installed Python 3.8. I am trying to change my string using the `title` method but I'm getting the following message when I run my code:

> <built-in method title of str object at 0x000001F4F841D870>

My code looks similar to the following:

```
name="allan"
name=name.title
print(name)
```

Why does `print(name)` result in this message?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly referred to it in your question, [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) is a *method*, not a property. Thus, you must call it with the proper syntax:

```
name="allan"
name=name.title()
print(name) # Allan
```